# How to select multiple roles from sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to rewrite this SQL code?

In this case the user is assigned to multiple roles.  I want all `Arrangemang` `ID`'s for the user's different roles in one list.

I want to refactor the hardcoded `@rollx` in these lines...

```
(kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll1) OR
```

If it's possible?

The following is my existing code...

```
SELECT kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrID,
       kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.Datum,
       (SELECT TOP (1) kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik
        FROM kk_aj_tbl_content
        INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent ON kk_aj_tbl_content.Contentid = kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.contentid
        WHERE (kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.arrid   = kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrID AND
               kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.Version = 1
              )
       ) AS Rubrik,
       (SELECT TOP (1) kk_aj_tbl_content_1.Underrubrik
        FROM kk_aj_tbl_content AS kk_aj_tbl_content_1
        INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent AS kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent_1 ON kk_aj_tbl_content_1.Contentid = kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent_1.contentid
        WHERE (kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent_1.arrid   = k_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrID AND
               kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent_1.Version = 1
              )
       ) AS UnderRubrik,
       kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.Publicerad,
       kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.LookedAt,
       kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus.ArrangemangStatus,
       kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemangtyp.arrangemangtyp,
       kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.konstform,
       kk_aj_tbl_utovare.Organisation,
       Users.Username
FROM kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_utovare ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.UtovarID = kk_aj_tbl_utovare.UtovarID
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrangemangStatusID = kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus.ArrangemangStatusID
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemangtyp ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrangemangstypID = kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemangtyp.ArrangemangstypID
INNER JOIN Users ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.AdminuserID = Users.UserID
WHERE (kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus.ArrangemangStatusID = @arrStatusTyp)
AND (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.VisningsPeriod = @visningsperiod)
AND ((kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll1) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll2) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll3) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll4) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll5) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll6) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll7) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll8) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll9) OR
     (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = @roll10)
    )
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Im using mssql.

Comment: Your question is tagged as "sql-server", can you change it to mysql?

Comment: @USeptim: why should he change it to `mysql` if he is using `sql-server`?

Comment: Sorry... I confused mssql with mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `IN` operator:

```
...AND kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID IN (@roll1, @roll2, ...@rolln)
```

Comment: I Will test that. Thx. Is it possible to pass an array to the stored procedure? So i can skip all the @roll vars. And just pass one var in.

Comment: SQL Server does not have an array data type, but it is possible to pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure if your sql client supports it (clients such as ado.net supports it).

Comment: I found this article http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html it talks about table-valued parameter (TVP) and functions that can help in this cases.  Thx for all help!

Comment: Erland Sommarskog is a highly respected expert in this field. As you can read, he also advocates the idea of using a table valued parameter if possible.